# Is the jerk caused by pseudo force when bus come to stop suddenly?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, inertia, jerk

If a bus stops moving suddenly, we tend to fall forwards due to the inertia of motion of our upper body.
But can we explain the sudden jerk in the forward direction due to some pseudo force? (Because I think according to an observer on the ground [inertial frame], the bus is a non-inertial frame {it is accelerating} - therefore pseudo force can be applied).

But can we show this sudden jerk in the forward direction due to pseudo force?

[image: Inertia of Motion of person in train]

Like this image showing this phenomenon in the train? [How can pseudo force be applied here instead of the inertia of motion].

Comment: From the perspective of an observer in the bus, the pseudo force is zero while the bus is moving at constant velocity, then, as it starts breaking, the pseudo force appears out of nowhere (has no obvious source), and grows quickly to some value, lasts a short while, then drops back to zero when the bus stops. The forward acceleration of any object is then attributed to this pseudo force.

Comment: Can you write as an equation using the mass and acceleration?

Comment: In a non-inertial reference frame, the apparent force is the sum of all the forces, *including* the pseudo force $F_p$. So, in this case, the pseudo force, the force of gravity, the normal force and the tension from the bus-straps: $F = F_p + F_g + N + T = ma$ (assuming the person is a rigid body). If this was a person floating in an accelerating spaceship, the pseudo force would just be $ma$, for the person's acceleration measured from the POV of the spaceship itself. In a bus, it gets more complicated because $F_p + F_g$ combine to pull you at an angle, and $T$ varies with time.

Answer (score 0):

> If a bus stops moving suddenly, we tend to fall forwards due to the
> inertia of motion of our upper body. But can we explain the sudden
> jerk in the forward direction due to some pseudo force?

Our inertia is the pseudo force. It's called an inertial force. It is pseudo (fictitious) because there is nothing making contact with us pushing us forward. Our bodies move forward during braking because our inertia wants to keep us moving forward, instead of stopping.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "because there is nothing making contact with us pushing us forward" - but that would disqualify all the fundamental forces of nature (as they are contactless - act at a distance). It's that there's no physical origin of the force, and the fact that it vanishes in an inertial frame, that makes it fictitious.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović The “inertial force” is not a fundamental force and clearly no non contact fundamental forces (gravitational, electromagnetic etc,) forces are involved here.

Comment: Clearly, at least gravity is involved in this situation. But that's not the point, you offered a method to identify inertial forces without qualifying it in any way - or, at least, the OP could see it that way. Don't you think that could confuse the OP, or even worse, potentially become a seed for a misunderstanding that will hinder them in their studies? It's good when you can make things simple, but there's a danger in being too handwavy.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović gravity is not involved with jerking forward which is what the OP is asking. The inertial force is only needed  in the non inertial frame of the bus. In the inertial frame of the ground there is no need to use a pseudo force to explain the person moving forward. That’s what they’re doing. Why don’t you post an answer of your own. In the meantime let the OP be the judge if I’m “confusing” him

Comment: How did my "that's not the point" remark cause you to focus precisely on the thing *that is not the point*? I'm saying that you just effectively stated that all forces are fictitious forces. That is what follows from your statement. And even if one doesn't take it as far, your unqualified statement, taken at face value, is *still wrong*. As for your protests - comments on this site are meant to be (among other things) a form of feedback, so that answers could be improved; if you don't like that, well that's your problem.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I DID NOT say that. Don’t put words in my mouth! I was only referring to the jerking foreword in the bus examples. This discussion is over

Comment: I didn't say you intended to say that, I did *not* put words in your mouth: I said that this is what follows from your incorrect statement that "It is pseudo (fictitious) because there is nothing making contact with us pushing us forward" - which remains incorrect even if you don't take it to that conclusion. You don't take feedback very well. Yes, this discussion is over: -1

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I take feedback well if its given in a constructive manner. Yours wasn't. I'm specifically referring to your response to my response to your first comment.

Comment: The only thing that could potentially be interpreted as non-constructive (which was not my intention) was me starting the sentence with "Clearly", but I just used the same word/phrasing you did in your previous response. The rest of it was me expanding on what my original comment was about, and on the motivation behind posting it. I glossed over the gravity aspect, because it was not the core of my objection, so if my terseness there came off as condescending, I apologize.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović "Clearly" was one. "or even worse potentially becoming the seed for misunderstanding that will hinder them in their studies" is another,  as if I am leading them astray.   Then I'm "handwaving" which is defined as "the use of gestures and insubstantial language meant to impress or convince".  In any case, apology accepted.

Comment: I see - it's a case of miscommunication then. I didn't mean to imply such an intent on your part (on the contrary, it was an appeal to your good intentions). I used "handwavy", which doesn't have the connotation you quoted (and is in fairly common use in education and academia, so I didn't think anything of it); it just means stating something without discussing subtleties or going into detail. "Handwavy [demonstration/proof/explanation] - one omitting important details or logical steps, perhaps instead appealing to laymen, common sense, tradition, intuition, or examples".